# Component to upload multiple images with client side crop

Tags: javascript, silverlight, flash, image, crop

I'm looking a quick way to add an (multi) image unloader with client side crop to an ASP.NET MVC site and for some reason the search seems to be much more complicated than I thought :(

- upload image (can be via form post or custom, just has to work with ASP.NET)
- custom crop possibility before upload
- (preferred) multiple images at once

**It doesn't matter if js/jquery,  silverlight or flash is used**, it just has to work, its an internal application and I can force people to have the necessary plugins installed.

**Basically this is exactly what I want:**
http://i-load.radactive.com/

But they are out of business and it seems impossible to get a license :(

**UPDATE**
This should be an all in one solution, I currently do not have the time to figure out how to connect multiple components.

I'm willing to purchase a component that does this, but I simply can't find one, which I find rather strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An internal application where you are comfortable with ASP.NET then Silverlight would be the good direction to look in.

There is free multiple file uploader which is designed to work with an ASP.NET server end here:  http://silverlightuploader.codeplex.com/

There are number of ways to manipulate an image in Silverlight, either natively or with other Silverlight tools such as: http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Finally you can re-encode images to common formats such as PNG with: http://imagetools.codeplex.com/

Whether you could actually combine these as is to acheive your goals would be another matter.

Comment: Thx, but it has to be an all in one solution, because I neither have the knowledge or time to put it together at this point.

Comment: @ntziolis:  I'm not sure that a "component" that does all that you describe really qualfies as a "component", sounds more like an app to me.

Comment: well the one i linked is exactly what I want, I would call it a control, but in the end it doesn't matter what it's called as long as it does the job. I have to say I'm quite surprised its so hard to find a alternative to the i-load control from radactive. These must be problems thousands of web devs have, they cant all do it on foot

Comment: @ntziolis:  "Problems thousands of web devs" have?  I'm sure there are thousands that want to upload multiple files.  I'm sure there are thousands that want client side image file manipulation. I'm not sure there are thousands in the intesect of these sets.  Of those left I'm not sure how many are so pressed for time that they can't take two components designed to solve specific pieces of the puzzle and put them to together.

Comment: i guess we have to disagree on that, there are even hundred of thousand web dev projects that that have implementd this exact functionality before, and to the fact way not put it together myself, its not even the time issue but I just couldn't believe nobody has put something together just yet. I'm accepting the answer since the info that there is no such component is an answer as well.